# Oracle 11g Instance that won't start

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I'm in need of some help with an Oracle 11g instance that won't start.  First of all, this is development instance so if it won't start it's not the end of the world, but it does have some useful data in it if I can bring it back to life.  This is running on a VM that was restored and since that time Oracle won't start.  Here is what I tried:

```
RMAN> startup

connected to target database (not started)
Oracle instance started
database mounted
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of startup command at 05/12/2014 13:01:08
ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF'

RMAN> recover database;

Starting recover at 12-MAY-14
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=63 device type=DISK

starting media recovery
media recovery failed
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 05/12/2014 13:01:23
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
RMAN-11003: failure during parse/execution of SQL statement: alter database recover if needed
 start until cancel using backup controlfile
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-16433: The database must be opened in read/write mode.
```

It seems like the ORA-01113 and ORA-16433 create kind of vicious circle.  I can't open the database until I perform media recovery, but I can't recover because I can't open the database?  Full disclosure - I work at a small shop that doesn't have DBAs and I'm a dev.

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

Comment: Obviously, Oracle has write access to the file in question?

Comment: I'll double check that - there were some issues with file permissions after the restore...

Comment: I don't know why Oracle wouldn't have write access.  Oracle runs as the system account and SYSTEM has "full control" when I look at the permissions for that file.

Comment: Even tried running the Oracle service as Administrator in lieu of SYSTEM and still the same behavior.